# Magento payment method in pdf

Tags: php, pdf, magento

I have installed the Fooman EmailAttachents which automatically attaches the pdf of an invoice to the invoice mail.

The problem I'm having is that with a certain payment method (via a gateway-module) the payment method field in the pdf is empty.

The strange part is that if I resend the e-mail, the field is properly filled. I have searced google to find only similar problems.

Comment: Hi there. Is there any good news about this problem. I'm gaving the same prob with my two payment methods.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you output the PDF at the point of attachment? This sounds like an issue with that extension or the gateway module not setting the payment method at the point that the email is generated.